# Direction vector perpendicular to two points

Tags: vector, direction

I have two points in space:

```
(x,y) (x2,y2)
```

Using those points I want to draw an object perpendicular to them. How can I find the perpendicular direction vector with those two points?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest would probably be:

(- (x2-x), y2-y)

This basically follows from the "Common Rotations" section on about [rotation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).  The negative of this vector is also perpendicular, it's up to you which one you want to use.

Comment: Almost! You actually have to swap x and y here to match the transformation of that 90-degree rotation matrix. i.e. if dx = x2-x and dy = y2-y, the perpendicular vectors are (-dy, dx) and (dy, -dx)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just flip the X and Y coordinates to find a line perpendicular?

Comment: I think that mirrors it around the 1,1 line